# Failure of Scalar gravity via Experiments

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations

I am looking for some papers or articles related with any experimental results which indicate Scalar gravity is wrong in some sense.

What i want to know explicitly is from what physical quantity observing from experiments rule out the scalar gravity model.

As far as i know, to  escape from some problems of scalar gravity model, [Brans-Dicke theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brans%E2%80%93Dicke_theory) was developed.

Any comment will be helpful!